# Combinar el plugin network con el loadingcontroller de ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript, ionic4

he intentado varias maneras de que cuando no se tenga internet, manda un loading y que se desaparezca cuando ya se tenga internet, pero nada me ha funcionado, solo me ha funcionado pero de manera muy extraña, y de la manera que tengo ahora solo me aparece el loading cuando no hay internet mas no se me cierra cuando pongo de nuevo el internet en el celular aqui mi codigo:

```
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private router:Router,
    private menu:MenuController,
    private logeo:LoginService,
    private nvctr:NavController,
    private activated_rout:ActivatedRoute,
    private network:Network,
    private loading_c:LoadingController 
  ) {
    this.network_check()
    this.initializeApp();
  }


  network_check() {


        // watch network for a disconnection
        let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
          this.loading_present('mostrar')
        });

        // stop disconnect watch
        disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();


        // watch network for a connection
        let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
         this.loading_present('esconder')
          // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
           // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
          // prior to doing any api requests as well.

        });

        // stop connect watch
        connectSubscription.unsubscribe();

}

async loading_present(condicion:String) {
    const loading = await this.loading_c.create({
      message: 'Esperando conectividad'

    })
    if(condicion == 'mostrar'){

        loading.present()

    }

    else{

        loading.dismiss()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que con esto `connectSubscription.unsubscribe();` está deteniendo el `onConnect().subscribe` si comenta esa línea y prueba de nuevo puede funcionar.

Comment: lo hice y no funciono, ahora ya no me muestra cuando esta desconectado o conectado

Comment: `this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
   this.loading_present('esconder');
});
this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  this.loading_present('mostrar')
});
`

Comment: ya lo solucione, lo hice por funciones aparte, una para el dismiss y otra para el present del loading